# Unity C#を用いて条件式に座標入力を行なう方法、その他　についての質問です。

Tags: c#, unity3d

ソフトウェア開発、プログラミング初心者です。
unity ver5.1.1f1、C#を用いて、スクリプト作成を行なっているのですが、煮詰まってしまった部分があるので質問させて頂きます。

A地点にあるObject(maincamera)がx<100というような一定の座標にある条件下で、space等のキー入力を受ける度にX方向に移動し、その条件から外れると（x>100など)Ａ地点に戻るというスクリプトを書こうとしているのですが、知識不足で上手く動作しません。

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mvcam : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void start () {
    }

        void update () {
//      int x;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-11, 0, 0);
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += 2;
        transform.position = pos;

//      Vector3 pos = transform.position;
//      transform.position = pos;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && pos.x< 100 )
//          pos.x += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        print(transform.localPosition.x);
    }
}
```

こちらの、`if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && pos.x< 100 )`の部分を「スペースキー入力があり、x<100の条件下にて」という条件式を書いているつもりなのですが、キーの反応が無く、実際は全く動作していません。

可能であれば、スクリプトの解説も交えてご教授願いたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && pos.x< 100 )`
の条件式についてですが、
キー入力を受ける度に、ということなら
キーを押下中ずっとtrueを返す`Input.GetKey()`でなく
キー押下したフレームでのみtrueを返す`Input.GetKeyDown()`を利用したほうが良いでしょう。

```
void update () {
//      int x;
        transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-11, 0, 0);
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        ...
        }
```

まず、update関数の頭文字が小文字になっています。
毎フレーム呼び出されるようにするには`void Update ()`です。
初期化に使うstart関数も中は空ですが、同様に頭文字が小文字になっていますね。

気になった点ですが、毎フレーム呼び出される場合、
`transform.localPosition`が毎フレーム`Vector3 (-11, 0, 0)`で初期化されるのは
動作として意図したものでしょうか？

`transform.localPosition`と`transform.position`が混在しているのも気になります。